# Why didn't any sin attach to Vishnu when he actively aided Indra in killing Vrtra?

Tags: vishnu, sin, indra, vritra

[How did Vishnu help Indra in killing Vritra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19797/how-did-vishnu-help-indra-in-killing-vritra)

> And Vishnu said, 'I am no doubt bound to do what is for your good. I shall, therefore, tell you of a contrivance whereby he may be annihilated. Do ye with the Rishis and the Gandharvas repair to the place where Vritra that bearer of a universal form is and adopt towards him a conciliatory policy. You will thus succeed in overthrowing him. By virtue of my power, victory, ye gods, will be won by Indra, for, remaining invisible, I shall enter into his thunderbolt, that best of weapons. O foremost of gods, depart ye with the Rishis and the Gandharvas. Let there be no delay in effecting a peace between Indra and Vritra.'

Vishnu was clearly an active participant in the killing of Vrtra.

Why did Brahmahatya attach only to Indra for killing Vrtra?

Answer (score 3):

Dharma/Karma is defined only for jIvas.

Vishnu is not a jIva. Even in avatAras, His birth doesn't restrict Him to a physical (composed of the 24 prakriti tattvas) body and hence His actions do not attract karma.

Source: Bhagavad-Gita (4.5 - 4.9)

On the other hand, the post of Indra is fulfilled temporarily by a jIva and therefore their actions attract karma. A jIva can become Indra by performing the right sacrifices such as Ashvamedha. When their speficic karma is extinguished, they move on from that post.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19033/which-vedic-verses-describe-indra-as-brahman

Comment: It is precisely to resolve issues like this we have chAga-pashu-nyAya (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/51226/10413). E.g bhU-sUkta refers to bhUmi as both indrapatnI and viShNupatnI. Clearly 'indra'  doesn't refer to shacIpati-devendra here.